Disable entityref decoding in html.parser
Python's html.parser.HTMLParser seems to alway decode entityrefs in attributes (e.g. translate &para; to ¶). Is there a way to disable this?
The HTML I like to parse is:
  <ul>
    <li>&para; &amp; &#xb6;</a>
    <li><a href="index.php?option=view&id=108">First link</a>
    <li><a href="index.php?option=view&params=28">Second link</a>
  </ul>

This is slightly misformed HTML: the <li> tags are never closed, and the ampersand in the href URLs is not url-encoded (it should be &amp;).
Sadly, html.parser.HTMLParser decodes the &params in the URL as &para;ms and returns ¶ms, as seen in this code:
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from html.entities import name2codepoint
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Start tag:", tag)
        for attr in attrs:
            print("     attr:", attr)
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("End tag  :", tag)
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data.strip():
            print("Data     :", data)
    def handle_comment(self, data):
        print("Comment  :", data)
    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        c = chr(name2codepoint[name])
        print("Named ent:", c)
    def handle_charref(self, name):
        if name.startswith('x'):
            c = chr(int(name[1:], 16))
        else:
            c = chr(int(name))
        print("Num ent  :", c)
    def handle_decl(self, data):
        print("Decl     :", data)
html = """
<ul>
  <li>&para; &amp; &#xb6;</a>
  <li><a href="index.php?option=view&id=108">First link</a>
  <li><a href="index.php?option=view&params=28">Second link</a>
</ul>
"""

parser = MyHTMLParser(convert_charrefs=False)
parser.feed(html)

The output is:
Start tag: ul
Start tag: li
Named ent: ¶
Named ent: &
Num ent  : ¶
End tag  : a
Start tag: li
Start tag: a
     attr: ('href', 'index.php?option=view&id=108')
Data     : First link
End tag  : a
Start tag: li
Start tag: a
     attr: ('href', 'index.php?option=view¶ms=28')
Data     : Second link
End tag  : a
End tag  : ul

The output shows that handle_entityref is called for the data, but never called for the href parameter. Hence, I have no ability to influence this behaviour, and I'm stuck with an incorrectly interpreted URL.
Is there a way to disable decoding of entityrefs by html.parser.HTMLParser?

html.parser.HTMLParser doesn't provide a built-in way to prevent the decoding of entity references in attributes. When you parse HTML, the parser automatically interprets entities as part of its normal behavior

After scrying HTML parser source code and doing some experiments I found it does depend at
from html import unescape

to deal with entityrefs and charrefs, therefore it is possible to prevent decoding them following way, firstly download parser.py
and replace
from html import unescape

using
unescape = lambda x:x

then doing
from parser import HTMLParser # remember to import from altered file
html = '<html><body><p>&para; &amp; &#xb6;</p></body></html>'
class CustomParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print(data)
custom = CustomParser()
custom.feed(html)

gives output
&para; &amp; &#xb6;

(tested in Python 3.10.12)

Interesting approach. However, changing a library feel more "Ruby" than Pythonic. I decided to use the external html5lib for parsing the HTML.
